# How to save photos in full resolution in android?

Tags: java, android, camera

I have made an app that uses the camera to capture images. The images are passed back to my application as `Bitmap`. I want to know how to modify my code to save the `Bitmap` into JPEG format at its full resolution?

```
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
out.flush();
out.close();
```

I think the `Bitmap` is being compressed into smaller size!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compression refers to the the reduction of physical disk space required to save the image. It doesn't automatically mean that the image quality or resolution is also reduced.

JPEG is part of a group of file formats that (mostly) belong to the [**lossy compression algorithms**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossy_compression). In other words some minor image detail and quality is sacrificed to reduce the file size of the image, but it still wouldn't reduce the resolution of the image.

If you want to reduce the file size of the image, but don't want to loose any image quality you need to use a file format which supports [**lossless compression**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossless_compression). You can for example use `Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG`.

WEBP supports both lossy and lossless compression (and is even smaller than PNG and JPG in file size). But support for WEBP was only added in API level 14 so there might be some backwards compatibility problems. Just use WEBP if possible, otherwise PNG if you care about image quality.

---

In any case let's look at the `compress()` method:

```
public boolean compress (Bitmap.CompressFormat format, int quality, OutputStream stream)
```

As you can see you can choose the `CompressFormat`, pass an `OutputStream` in and pick a quality. The number you pass in as quality can be between 0 and 100 and it determines if you compress either lossy or lossless. Since you pass in 100 the compression will always be lossless regardless of which `CompressFormat` you pick!

<sub>As an aside: Since PNG only supports lossless compression it will ignore the quality parameter completely and always save the image without reducing its quality!</sub>